# Signing with right key but still wrong key error on google play console

Tags: flutter, dart

I am signing my application all is perfect when I upload my app bundle  google play said 
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1: 21:**********************************.
when I read my  key store from key store explorer it show the same finger print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be late but I am pretty sure you did sign it with wrong key I recommend to double check first.

Comment: thanks for your answer I found my mistake I was signing with wrong key.